# Can't unhide rig with Auto-Rig Pro

Tags: rigging

I did rigging with auto-rig pro and now i can't unhide the rig. alt+h doesn't work. "Object" -> "Visibility" -> "Show in Viewports" is checked. According to scene collection, the rig exists and everything should be visible. rig not visible in picture[image]

Comment: That's a third-party addon so questions about it are really off-topic here, however there's a 'Viewport Display' dropdown in your image in the bottom right red box. Is anything in there disabled? You could also expand the 'rig' dropdown in the top-right outliner and see if the visibility of anything in there is disabled.

Comment: Try refreshing the 3D view, by clicking on it and/or entering Pose mode/Object mode. Check also if bone layers are active (Properties panel, little green man icon).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I just ran into this exact problem while trying to weight paint a tongue (during which I hid almost the entire rig). After 20 minutes of headache, I figured it out. I hope this helps someone.

The bones in the metarig and the DEF bones in the rig are exactly the same shape and exist in the exact same place, which makes this tricky. You have to make sure you're selecting the right bones. For me, this meant doing these steps in order :

1. Hiding the metarig (and, optionally, anything else in the way of selecting the little bit of the rig still unhidden)
2. Selecting the bit of the rig still unhidden
3. Entering *Pose Mode* with that, not the metarig, selected
4. THEN press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide the rest of it.

I'm still learning, so I must admit I currently live in fear of what I'll do if I ever inadvertently hide the whole rig with <kbd>H</kbd>.

(I also want to add that Rigify is not a *3rd-party* add-on - it ships with Blender - so unless I'm missing something, this question is quite valid here.)

Comment: Please note that the question above is not about *Rigify*, but about *Auto Rig Pro* which is a paid 3rd-party add-on.